# Mule ldap connector not working xsd issue

Tags: xsd, ldap, mule, mule-studio

In mule ldap connector examples shows xsd available in the http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap/3.3/mule-ldap.xsd. But runtime it shows error, as this xsd not existsing. I browsed http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ there is no ldap directory after that. Any change in the ldap connector support? Am I wrong using mulestudio(3.5)? I used demo application in the https://github.com/mulesoft/ldap-connector

I'm getting an error like this 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 122; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap/3.3/mule-ldap.xsd'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the Mule LDAP conncetor is having support only for Mule 3.3.2 and Mule 3.4 versions.

Try changing the schema declaration to the below one.

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:ldap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap
           http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ldap/current/mule-ldap.xsd">

  <!-- here goes your flows and configuration elements -->

</mule>
```

If not try changing you Mule version to 3.4.

Please refer to the link below for more details

[Mule LDAP Connector](http://www.mulesoft.org/connectors/ldap-connector)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the LDAP connector in your build path? XSDs are always present in your JARs but not always on the web. If you're using MuleStudio, all you need to do is to drag an LDAP message processor from the palette into your flow. Doing so will cause MuleStudio to load the necessary libraries for the LDAP connector and modify your namespaces accordingly.

Judging by the error that you posted, it seems that you are missing a JAR file from your build path. If you are using a Maven project, you can take a look [here](http://mulesoft.github.io/ldap-connector/guide/install) to learn how to add the necessary dependencies to your pom.xml file. If you're working with a normal Mule project, dragging and dropping an LDAP message processor into your flow should be enough.

I should mention that you need to install the LDAP connector in Mule Studio before you can use it. You can do so through the Cloud Connectors update site that comes bundled with Mule Studio. You can access this update site by going on Help > Install New Software and choosing it from the drop down list.

If you're interested in learning more on how to use Mule, we host a number of interesting blog posts on http://blog.ricston.com.